# c# / unity programming

Tags: c#

very new to programming and only starting my course in Jan. so would really appreciate if someone can help me make 2 pieces of code 1. what I want to do is make unlimited terrain in unity, then the terrain should procedural generate. both pieces of code are already done but i don't know how to make them work together... please help.

i want to make the terrain infinite and already have the code, but in the procedural generation i can only make it work on the specified number like this(2).. see below

```
//Terrain settings
    public int m_tilesX = 2; //Number of terrain tiles on the x axis
    public int m_tilesZ = 2; //Number of terrain tiles on the z axis
    public float m_pixelMapError = 6.0f; //A lower pixel error will draw terrain at a higher Level of detail but will be slower
    public float m_baseMapDist = 1000.0f; //The distance at which the low res base map will be drawn. Decrease to increase performance
```

unlimited terrain-

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InfiniteTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PlayerObject;

    private Terrain[,] _terrainGrid = new Terrain[3,3];

    void Start ()
    {
        Terrain linkedTerrain = gameObject.GetComponent<Terrain>();

        _terrainGrid[0,0] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[0,1] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[0,2] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[1,0] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[1,1] = linkedTerrain;
        _terrainGrid[1,2] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[2,0] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[2,1] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
        _terrainGrid[2,2] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();

        UpdateTerrainPositionsAndNeighbors();
    }

    private void UpdateTerrainPositionsAndNeighbors()
    {
        _terrainGrid[0,0].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x - _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z + _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.z);
        _terrainGrid[0,1].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x - _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z);
        _terrainGrid[0,2].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x - _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z - _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.z);

        _terrainGrid[1,0].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z + _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.z);
        _terrainGrid[1,2].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z - _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.z);

        _terrainGrid[2,0].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x + _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z + _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.z);
        _terrainGrid[2,1].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x + _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z);
        _terrainGrid[2,2].transform.position = new Vector3(
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.x + _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.x,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.y,
            _terrainGrid[1,1].transform.position.z - _terrainGrid[1,1].terrainData.size.z);

        _terrainGrid[0,0].SetNeighbors(             null,              null, _terrainGrid[1,0], _terrainGrid[0,1]);
        _terrainGrid[0,1].SetNeighbors(             null, _terrainGrid[0,0], _terrainGrid[1,1], _terrainGrid[0,2]);
        _terrainGrid[0,2].SetNeighbors(             null, _terrainGrid[0,1], _terrainGrid[1,2],              null);
        _terrainGrid[1,0].SetNeighbors(_terrainGrid[0,0],              null, _terrainGrid[2,0], _terrainGrid[1,1]);
        _terrainGrid[1,1].SetNeighbors(_terrainGrid[0,1], _terrainGrid[1,0], _terrainGrid[2,1], _terrainGrid[1,2]);
        _terrainGrid[1,2].SetNeighbors(_terrainGrid[0,2], _terrainGrid[1,1], _terrainGrid[2,2],              null);
        _terrainGrid[2,0].SetNeighbors(_terrainGrid[1,0],              null,              null, _terrainGrid[2,1]);
        _terrainGrid[2,1].SetNeighbors(_terrainGrid[1,1], _terrainGrid[2,0],              null, _terrainGrid[2,2]);
        _terrainGrid[2,2].SetNeighbors(_terrainGrid[1,2], _terrainGrid[2,1],              null,              null);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Vector3 playerPosition = new Vector3(PlayerObject.transform.position.x, PlayerObject.transform.position.y, PlayerObject.transform.position.z);
        Terrain playerTerrain = null;
        int xOffset = 0;
        int yOffset = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                if ((playerPosition.x >= _terrainGrid[x,y].transform.position.x) &&
                    (playerPosition.x <= (_terrainGrid[x,y].transform.position.x + _terrainGrid[x,y].terrainData.size.x)) &&
                    (playerPosition.z >= _terrainGrid[x,y].transform.position.z) &&
                    (playerPosition.z <= (_terrainGrid[x,y].transform.position.z + _terrainGrid[x,y].terrainData.size.z)))
                {
                    playerTerrain = _terrainGrid[x,y];
                    xOffset = 1 - x;
                    yOffset = 1 - y;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (playerTerrain != null)
                break;
        }

        if (playerTerrain != _terrainGrid[1,1])
        {
            Terrain[,] newTerrainGrid = new Terrain[3,3];
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    int newX = x + xOffset;
                    if (newX < 0)
                        newX = 2;
                    else if (newX > 2)
                        newX = 0;
                    int newY = y + yOffset;
                    if (newY < 0)
                        newY = 2;
                    else if (newY > 2)
                        newY = 0;
                    newTerrainGrid[newX, newY] = _terrainGrid[x,y];
                }
            _terrainGrid = newTerrainGrid;
            UpdateTerrainPositionsAndNeighbors();
        }
    }
}
```

procedural generation-

```
public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Prototypes
    public Texture2D m_splat0, m_splat1;
    public float m_splatTileSize0 = 10.0f;
    public float m_splatTileSize1 = 2.0f;
    public Texture2D m_detail0, m_detail1, m_detail2;
    public GameObject m_tree0, m_tree1, m_tree2;
    //Noise settings. A higher frq will create larger scale details. Each seed value will create a unique look
    public int m_groundSeed = 0;
    public float m_groundFrq = 800.0f;
    public int m_mountainSeed = 1;
    public float m_mountainFrq = 1200.0f;
    public int m_treeSeed = 2;
    public float m_treeFrq = 400.0f;
    public int m_detailSeed = 3;
    public float m_detailFrq = 100.0f;
    //Terrain settings
    public int m_tilesX = 2; //Number of terrain tiles on the x axis
    public int m_tilesZ = 2; //Number of terrain tiles on the z axis
    public float m_pixelMapError = 6.0f; //A lower pixel error will draw terrain at a higher Level of detail but will be slower
    public float m_baseMapDist = 1000.0f; //The distance at which the low res base map will be drawn. Decrease to increase performance
    //Terrain data settings
    public int m_heightMapSize = 513; //Higher number will create more detailed height maps
    public int m_alphaMapSize = 1024; //This is the control map that controls how the splat textures will be blended
    public int m_terrainSize = 2048;
    public int m_terrainHeight = 512;
    public int m_detailMapSize = 512; //Resolutions of detail (Grass) layers
    //Tree settings
    public int m_treeSpacing = 32; //spacing between trees
    public float m_treeDistance = 2000.0f; //The distance at which trees will no longer be drawn
    public float m_treeBillboardDistance = 400.0f; //The distance at which trees meshes will turn into tree billboards
    public float m_treeCrossFadeLength = 20.0f; //As trees turn to billboards there transform is rotated to match the meshes, a higher number will make this transition smoother
    public int m_treeMaximumFullLODCount = 400; //The maximum number of trees that will be drawn in a certain area. 
    //Detail settings
    public DetailRenderMode detailMode;
    public int m_detailObjectDistance = 400; //The distance at which details will no longer be drawn
    public float m_detailObjectDensity = 4.0f; //Creates more dense details within patch
    public int m_detailResolutionPerPatch = 32; //The size of detail patch. A higher number may reduce draw calls as details will be batch in larger patches
    public float m_wavingGrassStrength = 0.4f;
    public float m_wavingGrassAmount = 0.2f;
    public float m_wavingGrassSpeed = 0.4f;
    public Color m_wavingGrassTint = Color.white;
    public Color m_grassHealthyColor = Color.white;
    public Color m_grassDryColor = Color.white;

    //Private
    PerlinNoise m_groundNoise, m_mountainNoise, m_treeNoise, m_detailNoise;
    Terrain[,] m_terrain;
    SplatPrototype[] m_splatPrototypes;
    TreePrototype[] m_treeProtoTypes;
    DetailPrototype[] m_detailProtoTypes;
    Vector2 m_offset;

    void Start()
    {
        m_groundNoise = new PerlinNoise(m_groundSeed);
        m_mountainNoise = new PerlinNoise(m_mountainSeed);
        m_treeNoise = new PerlinNoise(m_treeSeed);
        m_detailNoise = new PerlinNoise(m_detailSeed);

        if (!Mathf.IsPowerOfTwo(m_heightMapSize - 1))
        {
            Debug.Log("TerrianGenerator::Start - height map size must be pow2+1 number");
            m_heightMapSize = Mathf.ClosestPowerOfTwo(m_heightMapSize) + 1;
        }

        if (!Mathf.IsPowerOfTwo(m_alphaMapSize))
        {
            Debug.Log("TerrianGenerator::Start - Alpha map size must be pow2 number");
            m_alphaMapSize = Mathf.ClosestPowerOfTwo(m_alphaMapSize);
        }

        if (!Mathf.IsPowerOfTwo(m_detailMapSize))
        {
            Debug.Log("TerrianGenerator::Start - Detail map size must be pow2 number");
            m_detailMapSize = Mathf.ClosestPowerOfTwo(m_detailMapSize);
        }

        if (m_detailResolutionPerPatch < 8)
        {
            Debug.Log("TerrianGenerator::Start - Detail resolution per patch must be >= 8, changing to 8");
            m_detailResolutionPerPatch = 8;
        }

        float[,] htmap = new float[m_heightMapSize, m_heightMapSize];

        m_terrain = new Terrain[m_tilesX, m_tilesZ];

        //this will center terrain at origin
        m_offset = new Vector2(-m_terrainSize * m_tilesX * 0.5f, -m_terrainSize * m_tilesZ * 0.5f);

        CreateProtoTypes();

        for (int x = 0; x < m_tilesX; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_tilesZ; z++)
            {
                FillHeights(htmap, x, z);

                TerrainData terrainData = new TerrainData();

                terrainData.heightmapResolution = m_heightMapSize;
                terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, htmap);
                terrainData.size = new Vector3(m_terrainSize, m_terrainHeight, m_terrainSize);
                terrainData.splatPrototypes = m_splatPrototypes;
                terrainData.treePrototypes = m_treeProtoTypes;
                terrainData.detailPrototypes = m_detailProtoTypes;

                FillAlphaMap(terrainData);

                m_terrain[x, z] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(terrainData).GetComponent<Terrain>();
                m_terrain[x, z].transform.position = new Vector3(m_terrainSize * x + m_offset.x, 0, m_terrainSize * z + m_offset.y);
                m_terrain[x, z].heightmapPixelError = m_pixelMapError;
                m_terrain[x, z].basemapDistance = m_baseMapDist;

                //disable this for better frame rate
                m_terrain[x, z].castShadows = false;

                FillTreeInstances(m_terrain[x, z], x, z);
                FillDetailMap(m_terrain[x, z], x, z);
            }
        }

        //Set the neighbours of terrain to remove seams.
        for (int x = 0; x < m_tilesX; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_tilesZ; z++)
            {
                Terrain right = null;
                Terrain left = null;
                Terrain bottom = null;
                Terrain top = null;

                if (x > 0) left = m_terrain[(x - 1), z];
                if (x < m_tilesX - 1) right = m_terrain[(x + 1), z];

                if (z > 0) bottom = m_terrain[x, (z - 1)];
                if (z < m_tilesZ - 1) top = m_terrain[x, (z + 1)];

                m_terrain[x, z].SetNeighbors(left, top, right, bottom);

            }
        }

    }

    void CreateProtoTypes()
    {
        //Ive hard coded 2 splat prototypes, 3 tree prototypes and 3 detail prototypes.
        //This is a little inflexible way to do it but it made the code simpler and can easly be modified 

        m_splatPrototypes = new SplatPrototype[2];

        m_splatPrototypes[0] = new SplatPrototype();
        m_splatPrototypes[0].texture = m_splat0;
        m_splatPrototypes[0].tileSize = new Vector2(m_splatTileSize0, m_splatTileSize0);

        m_splatPrototypes[1] = new SplatPrototype();
        m_splatPrototypes[1].texture = m_splat1;
        m_splatPrototypes[1].tileSize = new Vector2(m_splatTileSize1, m_splatTileSize1);

        m_treeProtoTypes = new TreePrototype[3];

        m_treeProtoTypes[0] = new TreePrototype();
        m_treeProtoTypes[0].prefab = m_tree0;

        m_treeProtoTypes[1] = new TreePrototype();
        m_treeProtoTypes[1].prefab = m_tree1;

        m_treeProtoTypes[2] = new TreePrototype();
        m_treeProtoTypes[2].prefab = m_tree2;

        m_detailProtoTypes = new DetailPrototype[3];

        m_detailProtoTypes[0] = new DetailPrototype();
        m_detailProtoTypes[0].prototypeTexture = m_detail0;
        m_detailProtoTypes[0].renderMode = detailMode;
        m_detailProtoTypes[0].healthyColor = m_grassHealthyColor;
        m_detailProtoTypes[0].dryColor = m_grassDryColor;

        m_detailProtoTypes[1] = new DetailPrototype();
        m_detailProtoTypes[1].prototypeTexture = m_detail1;
        m_detailProtoTypes[1].renderMode = detailMode;
        m_detailProtoTypes[1].healthyColor = m_grassHealthyColor;
        m_detailProtoTypes[1].dryColor = m_grassDryColor;

        m_detailProtoTypes[2] = new DetailPrototype();
        m_detailProtoTypes[2].prototypeTexture = m_detail2;
        m_detailProtoTypes[2].renderMode = detailMode;
        m_detailProtoTypes[2].healthyColor = m_grassHealthyColor;
        m_detailProtoTypes[2].dryColor = m_grassDryColor;


    }

    void FillHeights(float[,] htmap, int tileX, int tileZ)
    {
        float ratio = (float)m_terrainSize / (float)m_heightMapSize;

        for (int x = 0; x < m_heightMapSize; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_heightMapSize; z++)
            {
                float worldPosX = (x + tileX * (m_heightMapSize - 1)) * ratio;
                float worldPosZ = (z + tileZ * (m_heightMapSize - 1)) * ratio;

                float mountains = Mathf.Max(0.0f, m_mountainNoise.FractalNoise2D(worldPosX, worldPosZ, 6, m_mountainFrq, 0.8f));

                float plain = m_groundNoise.FractalNoise2D(worldPosX, worldPosZ, 4, m_groundFrq, 0.1f) + 0.1f;

                htmap[z, x] = plain + mountains;
            }
        }
    }

    void FillAlphaMap(TerrainData terrainData)
    {
        float[, ,] map = new float[m_alphaMapSize, m_alphaMapSize, 2];

        Random.seed = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < m_alphaMapSize; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_alphaMapSize; z++)
            {
                // Get the normalized terrain coordinate that
                // corresponds to the the point.
                float normX = x * 1.0f / (m_alphaMapSize - 1);
                float normZ = z * 1.0f / (m_alphaMapSize - 1);

                // Get the steepness value at the normalized coordinate.
                float angle = terrainData.GetSteepness(normX, normZ);

                // Steepness is given as an angle, 0..90 degrees. Divide
                // by 90 to get an alpha blending value in the range 0..1.
                float frac = angle / 90.0f;
                map[z, x, 0] = frac;
                map[z, x, 1] = 1.0f - frac;

            }
        }

        terrainData.alphamapResolution = m_alphaMapSize;
        terrainData.SetAlphamaps(0, 0, map);
    }

    void FillTreeInstances(Terrain terrain, int tileX, int tileZ)
    {
        Random.seed = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < m_terrainSize; x += m_treeSpacing)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_terrainSize; z += m_treeSpacing)
            {

                float unit = 1.0f / (m_terrainSize - 1);

                float offsetX = Random.value * unit * m_treeSpacing;
                float offsetZ = Random.value * unit * m_treeSpacing;

                float normX = x * unit + offsetX;
                float normZ = z * unit + offsetZ;

                // Get the steepness value at the normalized coordinate.
                float angle = terrain.terrainData.GetSteepness(normX, normZ);

                // Steepness is given as an angle, 0..90 degrees. Divide
                // by 90 to get an alpha blending value in the range 0..1.
                float frac = angle / 90.0f;

                if (frac < 0.5f) //make sure tree are not on steep slopes
                {
                    float worldPosX = x + tileX * (m_terrainSize - 1);
                    float worldPosZ = z + tileZ * (m_terrainSize - 1);

                    float noise = m_treeNoise.FractalNoise2D(worldPosX, worldPosZ, 3, m_treeFrq, 1.0f);
                    float ht = terrain.terrainData.GetInterpolatedHeight(normX, normZ);

                    if (noise > 0.0f && ht < m_terrainHeight * 0.4f)
                    {

                        TreeInstance temp = new TreeInstance();
                        temp.position = new Vector3(normX, ht, normZ);
                        temp.prototypeIndex = Random.Range(0, 3);
                        temp.widthScale = 1;
                        temp.heightScale = 1;
                        temp.color = Color.white;
                        temp.lightmapColor = Color.white;

                        terrain.AddTreeInstance(temp);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        terrain.treeDistance = m_treeDistance;
        terrain.treeBillboardDistance = m_treeBillboardDistance;
        terrain.treeCrossFadeLength = m_treeCrossFadeLength;
        terrain.treeMaximumFullLODCount = m_treeMaximumFullLODCount;

    }

    void FillDetailMap(Terrain terrain, int tileX, int tileZ)
    {
        //each layer is drawn separately so if you have a lot of layers your draw calls will increase 
        int[,] detailMap0 = new int[m_detailMapSize, m_detailMapSize];
        int[,] detailMap1 = new int[m_detailMapSize, m_detailMapSize];
        int[,] detailMap2 = new int[m_detailMapSize, m_detailMapSize];

        float ratio = (float)m_terrainSize / (float)m_detailMapSize;

        Random.seed = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < m_detailMapSize; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_detailMapSize; z++)
            {
                detailMap0[z, x] = 0;
                detailMap1[z, x] = 0;
                detailMap2[z, x] = 0;

                float unit = 1.0f / (m_detailMapSize - 1);

                float normX = x * unit;
                float normZ = z * unit;

                // Get the steepness value at the normalized coordinate.
                float angle = terrain.terrainData.GetSteepness(normX, normZ);

                // Steepness is given as an angle, 0..90 degrees. Divide
                // by 90 to get an alpha blending value in the range 0..1.
                float frac = angle / 90.0f;

                if (frac < 0.5f)
                {
                    float worldPosX = (x + tileX * (m_detailMapSize - 1)) * ratio;
                    float worldPosZ = (z + tileZ * (m_detailMapSize - 1)) * ratio;

                    float noise = m_detailNoise.FractalNoise2D(worldPosX, worldPosZ, 3, m_detailFrq, 1.0f);

                    if (noise > 0.0f)
                    {
                        float rnd = Random.value;
                        //Randomly select what layer to use
                        if (rnd < 0.33f)
                            detailMap0[z, x] = 1;
                        else if (rnd < 0.66f)
                            detailMap1[z, x] = 1;
                        else
                            detailMap2[z, x] = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        terrain.terrainData.wavingGrassStrength = m_wavingGrassStrength;
        terrain.terrainData.wavingGrassAmount = m_wavingGrassAmount;
        terrain.terrainData.wavingGrassSpeed = m_wavingGrassSpeed;
        terrain.terrainData.wavingGrassTint = m_wavingGrassTint;
        terrain.detailObjectDensity = m_detailObjectDensity;
        terrain.detailObjectDistance = m_detailObjectDistance;
        terrain.terrainData.SetDetailResolution(m_detailMapSize, m_detailResolutionPerPatch);

        terrain.terrainData.SetDetailLayer(0, 0, 0, detailMap0);
        terrain.terrainData.SetDetailLayer(0, 0, 1, detailMap1);
        terrain.terrainData.SetDetailLayer(0, 0, 2, detailMap2);

    }


}
```

so basically, i want the procedural generation to generate using the infinite terrain and not the (2), please help someone.

Comment: Maybe you could show what you have tried yourself to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lol I've worked with that terrain generator, if you are new to Unity, yet alone new to programming I would 100% advise you not to use that. That terrain generator uses perlin noise to create noise on the terrain (hills, and valleys), has nothing to do with making unlimited terrain. It's very performance heavy and I wouldn't use it unless you know what you're doing. Not to mention the fact that that terrain generator (I've used it before) is way above your head programming wise. Not something you can just plug in your game and understand without knowing basic programming concepts like OOP, data structures, algorithms..etc

PS your title is misleading 'stored procedures' is a database term and has nothing to do with Unity3D.

**UPDATE** 
Per request I found a good starter project for infinite terrain, you can download it and play around with it and I suggest to de-engineer it and really learn what's going on so you can make more complicated stuff later :)

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/infinite-terrain-free-project-source.68807/